# Fastlink 2.0 Aggregation URLs from FastLink 1.0

Tags: yodlee

We currently have credentials and access to FastLink 1.0.  I'd like to try FastLink 2.0.

The documentation I found @ https://developer.yodlee.com/Fastlink_2.0/FastLink_Integration_Guide_for_Web is okay but I am missing a couple key pieces of information.

Questions:

- Can FastLink 1.0 users immediately try FastLink 2.0 or is there a setup/migration step?
- It looks like FastLink 2.0 uses a different oauth tokening endpoint, is that the case?
- How do I create the FastLink 2.0 URLs from my current FastLink 1.0 and REST urls, specifically:

  - "Getting the token": `http://<REST_URL>/authenticator/token`
  - "Rsession Based Launch Parameter": `http://<node domain>/authenticate/<cobAppName>/`
  - What is our `REST_URL` base?
  - What value would we use for `<cobAppName>`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Fastlink 2, a separate provisioning is required and its not available Out of box. YOu will need to contact your respective Sales Counterpart for enabling the same.

Yeah, Fastlink2 is based on a different architecture all-together. End points etc will be different.

Once Fastlink2 is provisioned in your respective environment, we will provide you the required end-point etc to invoke the same.

Regards,
Vishal
Yodlee Interactive